# How to show Space required label in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to show Space required label in Inno setup?

[image: Space required label]

Comment: What exactly are you asking, what is the problem ? That label is visible by default and there is nothing that would change it. Could you edit your question and elaborate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this label is visible by default, but you can change it's visibility with this code:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Visible := True; // False to hide
end;
```

Comment: That label is visible by default  (Yes i Know) But in my script something is different.

Comment: @Leogreen, if there's *something different* in your script, you should show it in the first place. That label is visible by default and there's no need to do what is posted here explicitly as long as you didn't override (or cripple somehow) the `DiskSpaceMBLabel` message, or if some code intentionally hides, or covers it with another control.